# Arrayname about XML serialization in C# language

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
[XmlRootAttribute("Order",IsNullable = false)]    
public class Order
{
    [XmlAttribute("pay_method")]
    public string paymethod { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string custid { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Cargo", IsNullable = false)]
    public Cargo[] Cargos { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("")]
    [XmlArrayItem("AddedService", IsNullable = false)]
    public AddedService[] AddedServices { get; set; }
}

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer();
var requeststring = xs.Serialize(request);
```

When I run this function, in the result I always get `<Cargos>` like this:

```xml
<Order pay_method="" custid="">
    <Cargos>
    <Cargo name=""/>
    <Cargo name=""/>
    </Cargos>
    <AddedServices>
        <AddedService name=""/>
        <AddedService name=""/>
    </AddedServices>
</Order>
```

I just want to get the result without `<Cargos></Cargos></AddedServices><AddedServices>`, and for example:

```xml
<Order pay_method="" custid="">
    <Cargo name=""/>
    <Cargo name=""/>
    <AddedService name=""/>
    <AddedService name=""/>
</Order>
```

How can I config with both:

```
public Cargo[] Cargos { get; set; } 

public AddedService[] AddedServices { get; set; }
```

Comment: What you want would be considered invalid XML, so i don't really see a way or reason to achieve this. The problem is that A doesn't contain the `Cargo` items but a Collection of them, named `Cargos` - the current result is the exact representation of your object

Comment: You could, however, change your structure so `A` is a collection, like this: `public class A: List<Cargo>` - however, this would be a `List` instead of an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not work with `[XmlArrayItem]` then, but work with `[XmlElement(ElementName = "...")]`

This should match your expected XML:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Cargo")]
public class Cargo
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AddedService")]
public class AddedService
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Order")]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Cargo")]
    public List<Cargo> Cargo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddedService")]
    public List<AddedService> AddedService { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "pay_method")]
    public string Pay_method { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "custid")]
    public string Custid { get; set; }
}
```

**edit:**
Just tried it (and it works):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
        var subReq = new Order { Cargo  = new List<Cargo>{new Cargo { Name = "test" }, new Cargo { Name = "foo" }}, AddedService = new List<AddedService>{new AddedService{Name="addedService"}}, Custid = "custId", Pay_method = "bla"};
        var xml = "";

        using (var sww = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
            {
                xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
                xml = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output (`xml`-variable):

```xml
<Order pay_method="bla" custid="custId">
    <Cargo name="test" />
    <Cargo name="foo" />
    <AddedService name="addedService" />
</Order>
```

Comment: Thanks you answer,but it cant solve my problem.I have edit my question again, and please help me again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know why i cant get. Beacause i using a not right namespace

Comment: OK，isee and i will do as what you say.